# How to set maximum value 1000000 of edittext in android?

Tags: android

I'm using an EditText Field in my app where the user can specify an amount of money.

I want to set that user can not enter more than 1000000 money.

Is there a way to limit the value?

Comment: No.It is not duplicate@DharmbirSingh

Comment: you need to apply a textwatcher and there you need to check your condistions accordingly

Comment: You can't set maximum "integer" value for EditText. Instead, you can use [addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) to observe when text changed and make the change you desire.

Comment: @BakaWaii No,you are wrong.because we can set "integer" value for edittext without using addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use in java

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
```

or in xml

```
  <EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:maxLength="13"/>
```

Comment: yeah..It will working for me..Thanx @ Rasoul Miri

Comment: you can even add android:inputType="numberDecimal"